# Palindrome-Testing Function

Tags: math, palindrome

I'm trying to make a palindrome-testing function for an http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-check-for-palindromes
exercise, and I don't understand why the below function doesn't work. I took out all non-letters, made  it lower-case- what is the problem?

```
function palindrome(str) {
  if (str.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '').toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('')===str)
  {
  return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You took out all the non-letters and converted to lowercase only the left side of the equation, then (after reversion) you are equating it to str which might still have uppercase and non-letters

Try:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '').toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('') === str.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '').toLowerCase();
}
```

Note that there's no need to do if(x) return true else return false, you can just return the boolean that's inside the if.